# How to create self-signed certificate using Ed25519 in C#

Tags: c#, x509certificate, client-certificates, mtls, ed25519

I have to generate X509 certificates using Ed25519. I know I should use `RequestCertificate` class from `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` namespace but seems that it doesn't support ed25519.

That's my scenario: I have private ed25519 key and basing on it I need to generate self-signed X509 Certificate that will be able to use in mutual TLS.

I don't have any idea how can I do this while using ed25519, because it seems there is not support for this curve. How can I do this?

Comment: The built-in .NET cryptography classes don't support Edwards DSA (EdDSA).  If you have an implementation of EdDSA, then you could create an [X509SignatureGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509signaturegenerator?view=net-7.0) to represent EdDSA, and use that with the `CertificateRequest` class.  Otherwise, you'll need to use something external (Bouncy Castle, directly using OpenSSL, using the OpenSSL command line tools, et cetera).

Answer (score 4):

Create a configuration file for OpenSSL, e.g. openssl-25519.cnf:

```ini
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = DE
CN = www.example.com
[v3_req]
keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = www.example.com
DNS.2 = example.com
```

You can use File.WriteAllText to a temp file to use it during the certificate signing whereas openSsl25519Configuration is a string of the configuration above, where you can interpolate in your dynamic values.

```cs
string tempCnfName = Path.GetTempFileName();

File.WriteAllText(tempCnfName, openSsl25519Configuration);
```

Then use OpenSSL to request a certificate signing request file, using your **private** key (example.com.key).

```
openssl req -new -out example.com.csr -key example.com.key -config openssl-25519.cnf
```

If you already have an existing private key, refer to the file path to the .key file in the process arguments:

```cs
string tempCsrName = Path.GetTempFileName();

Process process = new Process() {
    StartInfo = {
        FileName = "openssl.exe",
        Arguments = $"req -new -out {tempCsrName} -key example.com.key -config {tempCnfName}"
    }
};

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

And now you can use OpenSSL again to self-sign `example.com.csr`:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 700 -in example.com.csr -signkey example.com.key -out example.com.crt
```

```cs
string tempCrtName = Path.GetTempFileName();

Process process = new Process() {
    StartInfo = {
        FileName = "openssl.exe",
        Arguments = $"req x509 -req -days 700 -in {tempCsrName} -signkey example.com.key -out {tempCrtName}"
    }
};

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

And now you have a self-signed ED25519 certificate that you can move or read as you need through tempCrtName.

If you don't already have a **private** key, you can generate one:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm ED25519 > example.com.key
```

Source: https://blog.pinterjann.is/ed25519-certificates.html

Comment: I know it's possible to do with OpenSSL. But I need to generate these certificates "on the fly" in C#.

Comment: You can achieve the same result using Processes in C#, I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: A clever solution. But it seems a not performance solution because we need to start a new process (and OpenSSL must be installed), we need to create temporary file, write to it at later read from it. Forgive me, but I think it's not the best possible answer.

Comment: I/O is not really an "issue" in performance talks, unless we're of course talking about using I/O as a large scale database - then yes of course. But writing to a file, reading from a file, 2 times in a somewhat large operation is not an issue at all.

Comment: I expect at least 20 certificates per second.

Comment: That sounds very sketchy...and undoable on a single machine/synchronous thread. What are you trying to do with all these certificates?

Comment: I need ephermal certificates for mutual TLS.